# Transformar planilha de presença e ausencia de espécies em colunas

Tags: r

Tenho uma dúvida básica sobre planilhas mas que está travando meu trabalho.

Eu tenho uma tabela de presença e ausencia de espécies com 714 sitios e 4406 espécies. Eu preciso transformar essa planilha em uma planilha com 3 colunas, sendo 1 com o nome dos sitios, 1 com o nome de todas as espécies por sitio (repetindo as 4406 espécies em cada sítio) e a outra com 0 (ausencia da espécie no sitio) e 1 (presença da espécie no sítio).

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: As funções melt (pacote reshape2) e gather (pacote tidyr) fazem o que você precisa. Se você atualizar sua pergunta com uma amostra dos seus dados, os usuários do SO podemos responder mais facilmente e com mais detalhes. Você pode rodar esta linha: `dput(seus.dados[1:20,1:20])` e copiar e colar a saída do console. Com isso qualquer usuário terá uma amostra das primeiras 20 linhas e 20 colunas do seu data.frame.

Answer (score 2):

Veja se é isso que precisa. Como não postou uma amostra dos seus dados, eis uma matriz fictícia de presença e ausência para usar de exemplo:

```
matriz.pa <- data.frame(
  Sitio = LETTERS[1:4], 
  A_arturica = sample(c(0,1), 4, replace=TRUE),
  A_beliniae = sample(c(0,1), 4, replace=TRUE),
  B_carmensis = sample(c(0,1), 4, replace=TRUE) )

> matriz.pa
  Sitio A_arturica A_beliniae B_carmensis
1     A          1          1           1
2     B          0          1           1
3     C          1          1           0
4     D          0          1           0
```

Usando a função melt (pacote reshape ou reshape2):

```
> reshape::melt(matriz.pa, variable_name = 'Especie')
Using Sitio as id variables
   Sitio     Especie value
1      A  A_arturica     1
2      B  A_arturica     0
3      C  A_arturica     1
4      D  A_arturica     0
5      A  A_beliniae     1
6      B  A_beliniae     1
7      C  A_beliniae     1
8      D  A_beliniae     1
9      A B_carmensis     1
10     B B_carmensis     1
11     C B_carmensis     0
12     D B_carmensis     0
```

O pacote reshape2 contém versões aprimoradas das funções do pacote reshape, mas o que você precisa é simples. Você também pode usar a função gather, do pacote tidyr, que faz a mesma coisa (mas com menos opções, embora, novamente, o que precisa é simples).

Comment: Para evitar o aviso `Using Sitio as id variables` pode-se usar o argumento `id.vars = "Sitio"`.

Comment: Sim! A opção `id.vars` também é importante se tiver mais de uma coluna que não é de valores, embora de maneira geral a função melt faça um bom trabalho detectando as colunas de id e dados.